# Updating to macOS 10.12.6 says the "volume does not meet the requirements for this update"

Tags: macos, software-update

When I am trying to update macOS Sierra 10.12 to 10.12.6 update I have this problem:

> macOS Sierra Update can't be installed on this disk. The volume does not meet the requirements for this update.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Pure guess... it needs more than 7 GB space to install

Comment: I made it 20 GB but still the problem

Comment: I am facing the same problem but I guess it is because I have virtualized Mac OS Sierra under VirtualBox in Ubuntu... :(